# linux shell get name of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writting shell script.

I have following files:

```
2012-03-08_16-37-41
2012-03-08_16-37-43
2012-03-08_16-37-46
2012-03-08_16-37-55
```

Simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME= ????
echo $FILENAME
```

And `FILENAME` value should be `2012-03-08_16-37-55` (last element of sorted file name list). Also, begin of file name should be `2012`.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FILENAME=$(ls -r 2012* | head -n 1)
```

Comment: Even better than mine idea :) +1

Comment: looks good but when 2012-03-08_16-37-55 is folder, the command is returning value of inside file.

Comment: sry. it's working. but returns with ":" at the end. How to remove it?

Comment: Martynas, you said the things being listed were FILES, not folders.  To make `ls` stop expanding folders, add the `-d` option.

Answer (score 2):

Don't [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) output. Instead, use find:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -name 2012* | sort | tail -1
```

To assign the result to a variable:

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=$(find . -name 2012* | sort | tail -1)
```

This also gives you access to all of the [many options find has](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html), including (not)following symlinks, recursion, only returning files (not directories), checking timestamps and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the `ls` command to get files, or just use "file globbing" to expand wildcards.

```
#!/bin/sh

for filename in 2012*; do
  echo "File (by globbing) is $filename"
done

ls 2012* | while read filename; do
  echo "File (via ls) is $filename"
done
```

To get the last one, the easiest way may be to sort the `ls` output:

```
filename=`ls -r 2012* | head -1`
```

But you can also just tail the glob, if you want to be messy.

```
for filename in 2012*; do
  echo "File (by globbing) is $filename"
done | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=""; 
for f in 2012* ; 
do
  # haha - don't do anything. 
  dummy=42
done; 
echo "now do something with $f"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external commands: `set 2012*; eval FILE=\$$#`. This is a perfectly safe use of `eval`.